# Insert an undefined instruction in X86 code to be detected by Intel PIN

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, intel-pin

I'm using a **PIN** based simulator to test some new architectural modifications. I need to test a "new" instruction with two operands (a register and a memory location) using my simulator.

Since it's tedious to use GCC Machine description to add only one instructions it seemed logical to use NOPs or Undefined Instructions. **PIN** would easily be able to detect a NOP instruction using `INS_IsNop`, but it would interfere with NOPs added naturally to the code, It also has either no operands or a single memory operand.

The only option left is to use and undefined instruction. undefined instructions would never interfere with the rest of the code, and can be detected by **PIN** using `INS_IsInvalid`.

The problem is I don't know how to add an undefined instruction (with operands) using GCC inline assembly. How do I do that?

Comment: From your question, your issue here is emitting an undefined instruction in gcc. From your comment it looks like another issue is decoding the instruction. Do you have this other issue or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that x86 has an explicit "unknown instruction" (see [this](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_318.html)).  gcc can produce this by simply using:

```
asm("ud2");
```

As for an undefined instruction with operands, I'm not sure what that would mean.  Once you have an undefined opcode, the additional bytes are all undefined.

But maybe you can get what you want with something like:

```
asm(".byte 0x0f, 0x0b");
```

Comment: the instruction is only undefined to GCC, to me it's a representation of my new instruction. Let's say my new instruction is add ADD OP1,OP2. I would use PIN to extract the operands then insert a call to INS_Delete() so that the instruction wouldn't raise an exception.

Comment: If the goal is to produce asm opcodes that GCC doesn't understand, you are out of luck. GCC doesn't interpret opcodes. Put anything inside the asm and gcc will just output it. If the goal is to output opcodes that the assembler doesn't understand, then you can use asm("xxx 1,2") and the assembler will reject it. If the goal is to output opcodes that the CPU doesn't understand, then you can use the "known" invalid opcode (ud2). How about something like `asm(".byte 0x0f, 0x0b, 0x90, 0x90")`. This should generate (something that looks like) a 4byte instruction that won't appear naturally.

Comment: Can you explain why `0x0f, 0x0b` are special? Are they invalid opcodes in x86, so that using them would result in an illegal instruction?

Comment: @umopapisdn Check out the [docs](https://mudongliang.github.io/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_318.html) for ud2.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a prefix that doesn't normally apply to an instruction.  e.g.

```
rep add eax, [rsi + rax*4 - 15]
```

will assemble just fine.  Some instruction set extensions are done this way.  e.g. `lzcnt` is encoded as `rep bsf`, so it executes as `bsf` on older CPUs, rather than generating an illegal instruction exception.  (Prefixes that don't apply are ignored, as required by the x86 ISA.)

This will let you take advantage of the assembler's ability to encode instruction operands, which as David Wohlferd notes in his answer, is a problem if you use `ud2`.