# Emulation of new instruction in Intel PIN

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, intel-pin

I am trying to emulate some new instructions in x86 using Intel PIN. For doing this I have created asm functions in a sample C program which would be passed as an executable into the PIN tool.

For example, the opcode 0x17 is illegal in x86-64, so I will be using that opcode to simulate my new instruction.  (It's `pop ss` in 32-bit mode.)  So I use something like this in my code-

```
asm(".byte 0x17");
```

However when I run my instruction trace using the PIN tool where I instrument instructions I don't detect the 0x17. This is the instrumentation function I am using-

```
VOID Instruction(INS ins, void *v)
{
  if(INS_Opcode(ins)==0x17)
  {
        INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)docount, IARG_THREAD_ID, IARG_END);
        INS_Delete(ins);
  }
}
```

I perform my analysis in the `docount()` function and then delete the instruction.

However I do not detect the illegal instruction at all.  For some reason the instructions I am getting do not share the same opcodes as the x86 ones.

I am compiling everything on x86_64 but still don't get anything. Anywhere I am doing something wrong?

Comment: 0x17 is valid in 16 and 32 bit mode. Are you sure your code runs in 64 bit mode?

Comment: My generated executable runs in 64 bit mode as I checked the instructions on gdb and it showed the 0x17 instruction as invalid. Not sure why it isn't seen in Pin though

Comment: Very strange indeed. 0x17 is `pop ss` in 32 bit mode, could you check if your binary crashes with an illegal instruction when run natively?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710769/insert-an-undefined-instruction-in-x86-code-to-be-detected-by-intel-pin mentions that invalid instructions can be detected with `INS_IsInvalid` in PIN.

Comment: closing as a duplicate of your other question for now, since I think sorting that out will answer this.  We can always reopen this if it turns out to need a separate answer.

Comment: @fuz turns out INS_Opcode(ins) does not give the exact assembly opcode so I guess my approach is wrong. Yes my binary crashes when I run my executable natively.

Comment: I tried INS_Valid(ins) in Pin, but it dosent detect the illegal instruction and simply crashes